# Querying on an attribute of a nested mongdb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to query on an attribute of a nested object but have no luck till yet. Let's say my document looks like :

```
{
"_id":"PE",
"code": {
    "5.1": "4.1",
    "5.2":"4.2",
    "6.1":"5.1",
    "6.2":"5.2",
    "7.1":"6.1",
    "7.2":"6.2",
    "7.3":"6.3",
    "7.4":"6.4",
    "8.1":"7.1",
    "8.2":"7.2",
    "8.3":"7.3",
    "9":"8",
    "10.1":"9.1"}
}
```

When i query `db.collection('xyz').find({id:PEI})`, i get access to this object, now from here I want to go inside code and lets say get the value `4.1` by using key `5.1` in 'code' object. How will i be able to achieve this? Thanks in advance!